# How to make python 3.11 my default python3 with brew

Tags: homebrew, python

I like new software and I noticed that 3.11 is available in brew, so I have installed it:

```
brew install python@3.11
```

I can get a repl by running `python3.11`, but if I run `python3` I still get python 3.10

I have unlinked python@3.10 and then tried linking python@3.11 and it tells me it is already linked (unlinking 3.11 first then relinking didn't help) and then when I try to run `python3` it gives me python3.9, which I believe is installed from `brew install python3` (If I try to remove python3.9 it tells me some software is dependant on it and I shouldn't do it...)

Anyway, is there any way to link the default brew python3 to use python3.11? I tried `brew switch` but I guess that command is deprecated...

Or is there some mechanism in brew that stops new versions from being used as a default?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Note: This applies to any versioned Python installation with Homebrew**

After installing Python 3.11, you are given the location of the bin folder with Python 3.11:

```sh
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /usr/local/bin/python3.11

Unversioned and major-versioned symlinks `python`, `python3`, `python-config`, `python3-config`, `pip`, `pip3`, etc. pointing to
`python3.11`, `python3.11-config`, `pip3.11` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /usr/local/opt/python@3.11/libexec/bin
```

You can add this folder to be first in your `PATH` and `python` or `python3` will pick up Python 3.11 (since those are in the folder):

---

So: add the following line to `~/.zshrc`:

```sh
export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/python@3.11/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

`brew --prefix` ensures that the correct path is used, regardless of where your brew install resides.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware that you can update your PATH in this way, but I want to know how to use brew to set 3.11 as my default, like I can with 3.9/3.10

Comment: You cannot until the default Python is updated to 3.11 which they don’t do until things are compatible.

Comment: For Apple silicon Macs, the export would need to be `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11/libexec/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: For the records, it is possible to manually symlink `python3.11` to `python3` via `ln`. But I do not encourage that since this will overwrite Python 3.10 and you may have broken dependancies and mess up `brew`.

Comment: I am confused here - the brew message says that python and python3 are symlinked to python 3.11

Comment: @sorin I fixed your attempted edit, HOMEBREW_PREFIX isn't a variable that exists but `brew --prefix` works

Comment: @mmmmmm the brew message says it created symlinks, also unversioned, _in `/usr/local/opt/python@3.11/libexec/bin`_ which is the crucial part. That dir will not be on `PATH` - `/opt/homebrew/bin` will be. `/opt/homebrew/bin` will contain an unversioned symlink `python3`, that points to some Homebrew `../Cellar/..` dir. For the OP, that was the cellar dir of Python `3.10`, and that's why `3.10` was invoked on a command `python3`.

Comment: @Ezekiel @sorin: it should indeed be `brew --prefix`. That command will, with some caveats, set `HOMEBREW_PREFIX`, but that variable won't be available until `brew --prefix` is first invoked. (I believe one reason for `brew` to automatically set the variable is so repeated use can refer to the variable rather than doing `brew --prefix` - if you need many of them in your startup files, it will accumulate some execution time since `brew --prefix` necessarily forks a new shell.)

Answer (score 12):

### On macOS Ventura & Sonoma on Apple Silicon

To install homebrew's version of python3:

`brew install python3`

This installs brew's version of python3.x but does not override the the link to macOS's version of python3 when you use the `python3` command. You can confirm which python3 is being used with the `which python3` command. Now, you have two primary options here:

1. You can unlink the system default's python3 and relink python3 to the homebrew version ([see kraspa11's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/455067/31585))
2. You can simply add an alias for python3 in your `~/.zshrc` file which can point to brew's version instead *(I prefer this because it results in fewer edits to system defaults)*.

If you prefer option #2:

Open up `~/.zshrc` with `nano ~/.zshrc` or your desired editor. *BTW, if you want to see "hidden" files/folders in your /Users/[username] folder where `.zshrc` resides, open your user folder in finder and press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (period). This will show/hide all hidden files and folders in your Finder.*

At the end of the `.zshrc` file, add the following lines:

```
# ensure "python3" command uses homebrew's version of python3
alias python3=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
# OPTIONAL: ensure "python" command uses homebrew's version of python3
alias python=/opt/homebrew/bin/python3
```

*I use `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3` instead of `/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.11`  so if/when you update your version from 3.11 to 3.12 and so on, your aliases should always work (until version 4).*

Now, save and close your edited `.zshrc` file. To refresh your terminal to use the new alias(es), enter:

`source ~/.zshrc`

To ensure that your commands are pointing to the brew version of python3:

`which python3` should respond: `python3: aliased to /opt/homebrew/bin/python3`

and

`which python` should respond: `python: aliased to /opt/homebrew/bin/python3`

*NOTE: I have only tested all of the above on Apple silicon macOS Sonoma (which is in developer beta, but should be functionally the same as Ventura).*

Comment: Those using Oh My Zsh might prefer to make a file something like `python.zsh` in your `$ZSH/custom` directory, and put aliases similar to the above for pip, python-config and whatnot.

Comment: This answer is slightly confused: there is system Python, managed by macOS, at `/usr/bin/python3` (a binary). Then there is homebrew Python, at /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 (a symlink to a specific homebrew-installed Python version). What version `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3` points to is up to homebrew; they choose a "latest stable release" and you can have later Python versions installed with Homebrew - that still won't be linked to from  `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`, and there are no `brew link` etc. commands that can force it to a later version than what homebrew has chosen.

Comment: If you want a command `python3` to invoke `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`, you can make sure the latter has precedence than (comes before) system Python in `PATH`. You could also set an alias or create a function `python3`. If you want `python3` to invoke a later Python version than what homebrew links `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3` to, you can modify `PATH` to have the desired `.../bin/` dir with higher precedence, or set an alias or create a function.

Comment: @carl I agree with everything you said. There's a lot of ways to achieve the same desired result and my way may not be the most optimized or direct way. Also, Jerry has a point...using the custom folder of zsh is probably the "cleaner" more modular way of customizing your zsh aliases etc...but I just wanted to lay out a quick and easy way of getting this to work for anyone that just wanted to start using Python3 with their (at the time, Beta version of MacOS).

Comment: you can use `$(brew --prefix python@3.11)/libexec/bin`

Answer (score 5):

List your python binary symlinks in `/opt/homebrew/bin` by running:

```
ls -la /opt/homebrew/bin | grep "python"
```

In your case python3 should be symlinked to python3.10. In my case, after running `brew unlink python3`, all python3.11(!) symlinks were removed from the directory. After that running `python3 --version` still showed 3.10.

After running `brew unlink python@3.10` all of my python3.10 symlinks were removed also, so that no python symlinks existed anymore in `/opt/homebrew/bin`.

Finally I was able to link python3.11 to `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3` by running `brew link python`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This didn't work for me (Ventura 13.3.1, python 3.11) .

Comment: @RobertAtkins please see my answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/461063/31585

Comment: This solution was useful for my particular use case on Mac OS 14.2.1 x86-64bit